# Error al integrar buscador y filtros ajax para tienda en linea

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy intentando programar una tienda en linea en la cual mi index posee un buscador el cual pasa los parametros a otra pagina llamada busqueda.php el cual recoge los parametros enviados pero en la página de busqueda.php manejo filtros los cuales funcionan con ajax, lo que no sé como hacer es como fusionarlos para que ambos trabajen correctamente ya que dentro de mi div que me sirve para recargar el ajax tambien tengo el codigo que recoge los parametros enviados por el formulario

codigo del archivo busqueda.php:

````
 <div class="row row-sm product-ajax-grid" id="mostrar">


<?php

                           if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){

$salida = "";
$condition  =   '';

 //$query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE producto_nombre NOT LIKE '' ORDER By producto_id LIMIT 25";
if (isset($_REQUEST['nombre']) and $_REQUEST['nombre']!="") {
        //$q = $_POST['nombre'];
        //echo "$q";
          $condition  .=  ' AND producto_nombre LIKE "%'.$_GET['nombre'].'%"';

    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['cata']) and $_REQUEST['cata']!="") {
        //$p = $_POST['cata'];
        //echo "$p";
        $condition  .=  ' AND producto_cat LIKE "%'.$_GET['cata'].'%"';

}
        $query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE producto_status = '1' $condition ";





    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
        //$salida.="";


        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

            $pro_id    = $row['producto_id'];
            $pro_cat   = $row['producto_cat'];
            $pro_marca = $row['producto_marca'];
            $pro_nombre = $row['producto_nombre'];
            $pro_precio = $row['producto_precio'];
            $pro_desc = $row['producto_desc'];
            $pro_imagen = $row['producto_imagen'];
            //$cat = $row['cat_nombre'];
            $pro_precio_final = $pro_precio-($pro_precio*($pro_desc/100));

            $salida.="
<div class='col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
                        <div class='product-default inner-quickview inner-icon'>
                            <figure>
                                <a href='product.html'>
                                    <img src='assets/images/products/$pro_imagen'>
                                </a>
                                <div class='label-group'>
                                    <span class='product-label label-cut'>$pro_desc% OFF</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='btn-icon-group'>
                                    <button pid='$pro_id' id='producto' class='btn-icon btn-add-cart' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addCartModal'><i class='icon-bag'></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <a href='ajax/product-quick-view.html' class='btn-quickview' title='Quick View'>Preview</a> 
                            </figure>
                            <div class='product-details'>
                                <div class='category-wrap'>
                                    <div class='category-list'>
                                        <a href='category.html' class='product-category' id='categoria'></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <h2 class='product-title'>
                                    <a href='product.html'>$pro_nombre</a>
                                </h2>
                                <div class='ratings-container'>
                                    <div class='product-ratings'>
                                        <span class='ratings' style='width:100%'></span><!-- End .ratings -->
                                        <span class='tooltiptext tooltip-top'></span>
                                    </div><!-- End .product-ratings -->
                                </div><!-- End .product-container -->
                                <div class='price-box'>
                                    <span class='old-price'>$$pro_precio</span>
                                    <span class='product-price'>$$pro_precio_final</span>
                                </div><!-- End .price-box -->
                            </div><!-- End .product-details -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ";


        }
        //$salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        $salida.="0 Resultados para esta búsqueda";
    }


    echo $salida;
}

                  ?> 

                        </div>```
````

Comment: ¿Este código esta funcionando? ¿Quieres saber si la aproximación es correcta o solucionar algo?

Comment: @Orici Lo que pasa es que el buscador que tengo en mi primera página necesito que mande parametros a otra página lo cual lo hago mediante un form pero si lo hago de esta manera los filtros ajax que tengo en la segunda pagina no permiten que se ejecute el codigo que muestro en la publicacion ya que se encuentran dentro del div con id="mostrar" en el cual aplico los filtros ajax que menciono, el codigo que muestro funciona si le quito el id=mostrar al div pero necesito que tanto los filtros como el buscador funcionen dentro del mismo div